# Is it possible to run the VBScript file(.vbs) from the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I have 10 .vbs file and incorporated them into a single .vbs file namely Main.vbs.Now if I double click on the main.vbs,my script got started to run. But I am looking for anyway can I run the .vbs file from the web browser? So that no one need to go to the directory where the Main.vbs kept and double clicked on it.

My Main.VBS contents:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim FSO : Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder
oShell.run "A.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "B.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "C.VBS", 1, True
oShell.run "D.VBS", 1, True
```

Comment: Only in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @RobW Yes that would be Great! if possible! but it should run on local machine! because the scripts i prepared is for kind of automation's on Excel sheet

Comment: `<script type="text/vbscript" src="main.vbs"></script>`

Comment: @RobW please see my Main.vbs content,which I want to run via the browser.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create a shortcut file and place it on your desktop? You could even assign a hot key to the shortcut file such as 'Ctrl+F12'. I wouldn't think you would want to lower your security settings to allow something like that to run through IE. On Windows 7 you should just be able to right click the vbscript and select Send To -> Desktop. It will create a shortcut on the desktop instead of having to navigate to the directory to click the file.

Comment: @Kyle What kind of security settings I would need it to run such .vbs through IE. Its on local machine and I would also like to run it locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can if you use Internet Exlorer, but you will have to keep your IE security settings low to run it and even then you could have a prompt to confirm.
All depends on which version and SP of Windows, which security updates , which version of IE and which settings in IE.

I suggest taking a second look at why you would start a local script this way. You can easily make and distribute a shortcut that starts your script without hassle of settings and prompts.

Ik you need a User Interface you can use Vbscript build-in or you could use a .HTA file instead of a .html or .asp file, security is less an issue with these files.

example: test.html

```
<script type="text/vbscript" src="c:\temp\test.vbs"></script>
```

and test.vbs

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set writefile = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", ForWriting, True)
writefile.write "test"
writefile.close
```

When i load test.html i get two prompts and when i confirm i get the output.txt in  c:\temp

And last here an example with a .hta file, save it as eg test.hta, alwyas use IE when using ActiveX or Vbscript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
<!--
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set writefile = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", ForWriting, True)
writefile.write "test"
writefile.close
'-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

or

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/vbscript">
  sub test
    const runminimized = 7
    const dont_wait_for_end = false
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "c:\temp\test.vbs",runminimized, dont_wait_for_end
  end sub
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  these are the instructions
  <button onclick="vbscript:test" >Run the script</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Give me the windows-7 platform solution, I just wanted to run the .vbs file,which now i am starting by clicking on it! these solutions I am looking for so that users not needed to go every time to the directory and click on that file rather to start from the browser!

Comment: Can you give me a sample to implement your idea here?

Comment: Shall I need to click on the .html file to run my Main.vbs?

Comment: in my case, with .hta version should i need to write main.vbs context within .hta file?

Comment: just load it as any other web-page, but you will get prompts i'm afraid, when you dont't want that consider using a shortcut icon on your destop, startmenu or something like that

Comment: no you don't have to, i just gave it as an alternative, see my last edit

Comment: my point is, the user needs to do an anction, load the page from a favorite, retrieve it from previous typed ursl or clicking a link, so why not just put a shortcut to the vbs on an easy spot ?

Comment: Because the users are not much educated,they are totally non technical. And the script i have written will be used on their personal desktop.So I was trying to give them some instructions also on the page before they run it.So with shortcut it is not possible. can I also put some instructions over there about the script that what to take care of ?

Comment: as per your last edit i will save it as .html file, then what would be its URL?

Comment: you can with messagebox and inputbox but that is ugly, then take the .hta road and put the instructions in html just like you would in a .html file, you can let them start the vbs by clicking a button

Comment: url; just the file unc like \\server\share\test.html or c:\temp\test.vbs, ie will convert it like file:///c:/temp/test.html

Comment: @can you show the code to create with such buttons and .hta as per your idea i am now going,lets make it more clear to users who would run such scripts on their end!

Comment: sigh, you as a lot, the purpose of this site is to ask advise, not that we write the ciode for you , but since it's christmas, see my last edit

Comment: What you did for me enough,Now I will use this concept to make my one!! thanks for your advice and giving a lesson with such .hta and .html file to run the vbscript code!!! happy Christmas to you n your family!!

Comment: VBSlover, the 7 is a constant for run minimized. It is passed in the function call for WshShell.Run along with a false value to not wait for the process to finish. It is considered good programming to declare these constants to values with names as peter did so that future coders can understand what was done.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a classic ASP page that includes your script files, execute them and report results to the browser.

Asp pages are served by IIS (depending on version you may need to configure ASP settings)  and can be run from any browser.

Answer (score 0):

For VBSlover's purpose the best way would be to program a [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (no need for the extra complexity of a web server, no security hassles as in a plain client .html script). Of course, just wrapping some HTML code around existing VBScript code would be fatal, you'll have to design a useful GUI and distribute the existing features into suitable event handlers. Definitely not a project that can be tackled by posting a barrage of questions here - some careful research of your own is a **necessary** starting point/pre-requisite.